# laravel placeholder translation of an array

Tags: php, laravel

i have a translation which is an array and i want to replace some string in the array. this throws an error

```
# translation
[
  'key' = [
    'b' => [ 
      'c' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'Extract ',
                    'text' => ':num_replace some text',
                ],
              ]
           ]
       ]
]


$result = __('key.b.c', ['num_replace' => $num > 0 ? number_format($totalModelsPositionsCount) : '']);
```

but this errors with `local.ERROR: strtr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` Can laravel https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization#replacing-parameters-in-translation-strings be used only in strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing key `text` :

```
__('key.b.c',
```

It should be :

```
__('key.b.c.text',
```

`Can laravel https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization#replacing-parameters-in-translation-strings be used only in strings?` : Yes

it takes an array of arguments and returns a translation string